# Blender stopped opening for me on windows 10

Tags: windows, installation

When I open blender, the command box pops up, goes away, a grey window opens and then closes immediately with no error message or anything. Even when running as administrator. From following some other posts on the issue I did manage to get an "exception_access_violation" error when running in cmd.

I've completely reinstalled blender multiple times now (always going in and manually deleting anything left behind after each install in AppData and program files) I've tried both of my hard drives, both 64 and 32 bit, both zipped and installer. I've tried reinstalling my graphics driver and running the intel processor updater (though it said there was nothing to update)

I've tried downloading a new opengl32.dll but putting it in the blender install directory did nothing, and when I try to replace the system32 one it says I need permission even after granting administrator permission.

I very recently completely wiped my entire computer and installed a fresh version of windows 10. and Blender was running fine for a while. The only thing I can think of that I for sure did between it working and not working is that I updated my graphics card driver (Nvidia GeForce GTX 1070. Now ver 416.94)

Anyone else having this problem? Any suggestions on fixes? I'm banging my head against a wall here.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the best way to solve mysterious bugs like this is to divide and conquer. Basically try to isolate things that might cause it and run experiments that rule those things out. What you end up with at the end will be the issue.

We can't really be of much help since this process requires access to the machine with the issue. But perhaps trying this method may help you.

So, you've mentioned you have an access violation? That, sadly for you, is the equivalent of announcing you've lost your needle in a particular haystack.

Something you could perhaps try is to run blender from the command line with some of its debugging options. For instance try

```
blender.exe --debug
```

There's no guarantee that you won't get a crash, but at this stage, its probably beneficial to try and gather more information that will narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: Sometimes the error happens because Windows sometimes decides that blender violates some policy for accessing the graphics system.  Usually there's a popup that allows you to white list blender.  Unfortunately, I don't recall how to white list when the popup doesn't appear.

Comment: So I'm not sure if I'm just doing it wrong (I don't use the command console often) but to open it I've been using the line 
cmd /K "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.exe"

When I try to add the --debug to it I just get "C:\Program is not recognized... error message.


Running my command again I did notice some other messages I didn't see before though:
AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead
found bundled pythin: "2.79\python directory"

Then the EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION error

Comment: Hi @AustinAlander, can you post the output of your console here? Please include the command you are using. Happy to take a look :)

Comment: Managed to get the debug command working I think. Got this: 


C:\Users\lilti>blender -d
Switching to fully guarded memory allocator.
Blender 2.79 (sub 0)
Build: Thu 03/22/2018 09:59 AM Windows
argv[0] = blender
argv[1] = -d
read file
  Version 272 sub 2 date unknown hash unknown

ordered
 OBCube
 OBLamp
 OBCamera
found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\python
Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Comment: Yeah, there's not a great deal of helpful information there, perhaps try enabling all debug messages, you can do this by changing from -d to debug-all, sorry I am on a mac OS system so the command might be different for you on windows. You should be able to get a list of all command line options by doing something like

blender.exe --help

Comment: Using help I found a "debug all" command that shows all available debug info. I have no idea what any of it means though. And it's way to long to post in this character limit, so [here's a screen cap.](https://i.imgur.com/4U3N081.png) But from what I can tell it all looks fine....

Comment: Hi Austin, hmmmm, the last thing to happen before the crash is to do with OpenCL. Given you recently updated your graphics drivers, have you tried rolling back to the version of drivers that was working?

Comment: I just downloaded the latest 2.80 beta and it opens fine. Any idea why it would work and not 2.79b?

Answer (score 0):

Today when I downloaded the 2.8 version Blender for my new computer, I met the same problem as you said.

I tried several solutions and they don't help.  Then I just installed a 2.79 version Blender and it works!

So try another version if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by right clicking on the Blender shortcut and choosing the option *Solve compatibility issue*.